# convert code from vb6 to code in c#

Tags: c#, struct, vb6, programming-languages, byte

I read this code in VB6 ,How can I write this code in c# languge

```
Type pix

b As Byte
g As Byte
R As Byte

End Type

Public img() As pix

wi=320
hi=240

ReDim img(wi, hi)
```

Comment: use this link it will help you better 

http://stackoverflow.com/q/179605/2445111

Comment: thank you but I want to write this  code in c#

Comment: Looks flawed anyway, allocating a 321 by 241 byte array.  You might look for better code to convert, that gaffe doesn't bode well.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Go to this [website](http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/vb-to-csharp/)  . you can paste your VB code and Click C# as an output and click convert. and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

### C#

```
public struct pix
{
    public byte r;
    public byte g;
    public byte b;
}

public pix[,] img;
int wi = 320;
int hi = 240;

img = new pix[wi, hi];
```

If you are looking for `ReDim Preserve`, see this [Redim Preserve in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327916/redim-preserve-in-c)